# File manipulations in C

Tags: c, file, mkdir

I am using a simple 'C' code to do the following:

1) Read from a .txt file.

2) Based on the string present in the .txt file, a directory will be created.

I am not able to perform step-2, as I am not clear with type conversions.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <direct.h>

int main()
{
   char ch, file_name[25];
   FILE *fp;

   //printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see\n");
   //gets(file_name);

   fp = fopen("input.txt","r"); // read mode

   if( fp == NULL )
    {
      perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);

   while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
      printf("%c",ch);

    if( _mkdir(ch ) == 0 )
   {
      printf( "Directory successfully created\n" );
      printf("\n");
   }
   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

Here is the error:

```
 *error #2140: Type error in argument 1 to '_mkdir'; expected 'const char *' but found 'char'.*
```

Comment: I'm a little confused about what *you're* confused about... `mkdir` takes a string, and you're giving it a single character. The compiler is saying the same thing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YES, compiler is right.

You are passing a char `c` to `_mkdir`, instead of a string.

You should read the string from file and store it to `file_name` (I guess you forget) and then

```
_mkdir(file_name);
```

See below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <direct.h>


int main()
{
    char file_name[25];
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r"); // read mode

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fgets(file_name, 25, fp);

    _mkdir(file_name);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK, I added this, still its not working

`while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
      printf("%c",ch);
 char str[25] = ch;
    if( _mkdir(str) == 0 )
   {
      printf( "Directory successfully created\n" );
   }`

Comment: @highlander141 , why not read from the file using `fgets()` ??

Answer (score 2):

It's because you only have a single `char` (the `c` in `fgetc` stands for `char`) while `_mkdir` wants a string (i.e. `char *`).

You should probably use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead to read the input.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use fgets , then you can use this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <direct.h>
int main()
{
char file_name[25];
String str;
FILE *fp;
char ch;
int i=0;

fp = fopen("input.txt", "r"); // read mode

if (fp == NULL)
{
    perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
 while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF ){
  printf("%c",ch);
  file_name[i];
  i++
}
str=file_name;

_mkdir(str);

fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```